# Relating the scalar curvatures of two Riemannian metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Sorry if this is a silly question. I recently read the post: [Relating the Ricci curvatures of two Riemannian metrics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4561084/relating-the-ricci-curvatures-of-two-riemannian-metrics) and wonder if there are any ways to relate the scalar curvature of two Riemannian metrics?

I tried to take the trace of the following equation
$$R_{ij}=\bar R_{ij}+(\bar \nabla_kW_{ij}^k-\bar\nabla_jW_{ki}^k)+(W_{kl}^kW_{ij}^l-W_{jl}^kW_{ik}^l)$$
i.e.,
$$R_g=g^{ij}R_{ij}=g^{ij}\bar R_{ij}+g^{ij}(\bar \nabla_kW_{ij}^k-\bar\nabla_jW_{ki}^k)+g^{ij}(W_{kl}^kW_{ij}^l-W_{jl}^kW_{ik}^l).$$
But I am not sure how to proceed from here. Are there any well-known relation between two scalar curvatures with respect to two different metrics $g$ and $\bar g$ on the same manifold $M$?

Comment: I don't think a nice formula exist for general $g,\bar{g}$.  On the other hand, if $g,\bar{g}$ are conformal then you have a conformal frame that helps a lot with finally contracting $i,j$ with respect to both $g$ and $\bar{g}$ (or computing the difference of their Christoffel symbols).

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you for your answer! I don't know if I should ask a new question in a new post or just comment on it here. Here is another situation: is it possible to relate the scalar curvatures between two manifolds, say, $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ in general? Suppose $f:(M,g)\to (N,h)$ is a diffeomorphism, are the scalar curvatures related somehow?

Comment: In general no.  For example, Aubin (1970) proved that in dimension $\geq 3$ every closed manifold admits a negative scalar curvature metric.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you very much for your help! Much appreciated!