# Linearization of scalar curvature: $DR|_g(h)=-\Delta_g(\mathrm{tr}_g h)+\mathrm{div}_g(\mathrm{div}_g h)-\langle\mathrm{Ric}_g,h\rangle_g$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, linearization

I'm working on an exercise from *Geometric Relativity* by Dan A. Lee, but things didn't go well:

> [image: Blockquote]

Following Lee's hint, I was trying to use Exercise 1.12 and view $\color{red}{g}$ as the background metric ($\bar g$ in Exercise 1.12). In Exercise 1.12, I've shown that the Ricci curvature of a Riemannian metric $g$ and the Ricci curvature of another Riemannian metric $\bar g$ are related by
$$R_{ij}=\bar{R}_{ij}+(\overline{\nabla}_k W_{ij}^k-\overline{\nabla}_j W_{ki}^k)+(W_{k\ell}^k W_{ij}^\ell-W_{j\ell}^k W_{ik}^\ell).\tag{1}$$
Please see [Relating the Ricci curvatures of two Riemannian metrics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4561084/relating-the-ricci-curvatures-of-two-riemannian-metrics) to know about (1).

Now I have
$$R_{g_t}=g_t^{ij}\bar{R}_{ij}+g_t^{ij}(\overline{\nabla}_k W_{ij}^k-\overline{\nabla}_j W_{ki}^k)+g_t^{ij}(W_{k\ell}^k W_{ij}^\ell-W_{j\ell}^k W_{ik}^\ell)\tag{2}$$
and
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}R_{g_t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{R_{g_t}-R_g}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{R_{g_t}-g^{ij}\bar{R}_{ij}}{t}.\tag{3}$$
To evaluate the difference quotient in (3), I write
$$R_{g_t}\simeq (g^{ij}+t\dot{g}^{ij})\bar{R}_{ij}+(g^{ij}+t\dot{g}^{ij})(\overline{\nabla}_k W_{ij}^k-\overline{\nabla}_j W_{ki}^k)+(g^{ij}+t\dot{g}^{ij})(W_{k\ell}^k W_{ij}^\ell-W_{j\ell}^k W_{ik}^\ell)\tag{4}$$
for small $t$. I'm not sure if the linear approximation of $g_t$ at $t=0$ is legitimate, but I can't imagine what it would be like if there were any other ways. Now I have
$$\frac{R_{g_t}-g^{ij}\bar{R}_{ij}}{t}\simeq \dot{g}^{ij}\bar{R}_{ij}+(\frac{g^{ij}}{t}+\dot{g}^{ij})(\overline{\nabla}_k W_{ij}^k-\overline{\nabla}_j W_{ki}^k)+(\frac{g^{ij}}{t}+\dot{g}^{ij})(W_{k\ell}^k W_{ij}^\ell-W_{j\ell}^k W_{ik}^\ell)\tag{5}$$
for small $t\neq 0$. If the above is true, all we have to do now is take its limit at $t=0$. But after seeing that
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\dot{g}^{ij}\bar{R}_{ij}=\dot{g}^{ij}\bar{R}_{ij}=\langle\mathrm{Ric}_g,\dot{g}\rangle_g,\tag{6}$$
I began to hesitate about the computation because I didn't have a minus sign to compensate (6) for the formula to be derived in Exercise 1.18. Why's that? What should I do next? Thank you.

**Remark 1.** I'm not worried about $\dot{g}^{ij}(\overline{\nabla}_k W_{ij}^k-\overline{\nabla}_j W_{ki}^k)$ and $\dot{g}^{ij}(W_{k\ell}^k W_{ij}^\ell-W_{j\ell}^k W_{ik}^\ell)$ in (5) because these terms contribute nothing as indicated by the hint.

**Remark 2.** The hint says that in any orthonormal frame $\{v_i\}_i$, the double divergence of $\dot{g}$ is given by
$$\mathrm{div}_g\mathrm{div}_g\dot{g}=\sum_{i,j}\dot{g}_{ij;ij},$$
which I have just checked. And in the same frame, I also checked that
$$\begin{align}
\Delta_g\mathrm{tr}_g\dot{g}&=\mathrm{div}_g\mathrm{grad}(g^{ij}\dot{g}_{ij})\\
&=\sum_k\left(v_k(v_k(\sum_i \dot{g}_{ii}))+\sum_j v_j(\sum_i\dot{g}_{ii})\overline{\Gamma}_{kj}^k\right)
\end{align}$$
and that
$$\langle\mathrm{Ric}_g,\dot{g}\rangle_g=\sum_{i,j}\bar{R}_{ij}\dot{g}_{ij}.$$
These local expressions follow from a straightforward computation. The crux of my attempt really lies in the expansion of those $W$ terms. Originally, I planned on taking it by employing
$$W_{ij}^k=\frac{1}{2}g_t^{k\ell}\left(\overline{\nabla}_i(g_t)_{\ell j}+\overline{\nabla}_j(g_t)_{i\ell}-\overline{\nabla}_\ell(g_t)_{ij}\right),$$
another result obtained previously (see [The components $W_{ij}^k$ of the difference $W=\nabla-\overline{\nabla}$ between two Levi-Civita connections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552475/the-components-w-ijk-of-the-difference-w-nabla-overline-nabla-between)), but the algebra really hurts.

Comment: It looks like you would need to expand $W$ in terms of $t$ as well.

Comment: @MathTheNovice Thank you. That's really what I'm trying to do now, in order to cancel $t$ in the denominator of $\frac{g^{ij}}{t}$ and take the limit at $t=0$.

Comment: I am too lazy to type all the details but [here on Prop 1.4](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=w5driqZlhAoC&pg=PA2&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) the calculation is carried out in normal coordinates.

Comment: @MathTheNovice The book you recommended is really great; at least, it makes me feel better to use the linear approximation of $g_t$. Thank you.