# Definition of the formal $L^2$-adjoint $T^*$ of a linear operator $T:C^\infty(T^*M\odot T^*M)\to C^\infty(M)$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, adjoint-operators

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $C^\infty(T^*M\odot T^*M)$ the space of all smooth symmetric $2$-tensor fields on $M$, and $C^\infty(M)$ the space of all smooth functions on $M$. I'd like to know the definition of the **formal $L^2$-adjoint** $T^*$ of a linear operator $T:C^\infty(T^*M\odot T^*M)\to C^\infty(M)$. For a concrete example of $T$, one can see

[Linearization of scalar curvature: $DR|_g(h)=-\Delta_g(\mathrm{tr}_g h)+\mathrm{div}_g(\mathrm{div}_g h)-\langle\mathrm{Ric}_g,h\rangle_g$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576865/linearization-of-scalar-curvature-dr-gh-delta-g-mathrmtr-g-h-mathrm)

to know about the linearized scalar curvature.

In a linear algebra course or a functional analysis course, it is a standard practice to define the **adjoint** of a linear operator between inner product spaces, but somehow I didn't find too much reference on **formal adjoints**. So far, I've got only one example: given a closed manifold, we know the gradient operator $\mathrm{grad}$ and $-\mathrm{div}$ are the formal adjoints of each other in the sense that
$$\int_M\langle\mathrm{grad}f,X\rangle_g dV_g=\int_M f(-\mathrm{div}X) dV_g\tag{1}$$
for every $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and every smooth vector field $X$ in $\mathfrak{X}(M)$. How about $T^*$? By analogy with the previous example and my experience of ordinary adjoint operators, it seems like I have to find a linear operator $T^*$ that goes from $C^\infty(M)$ to $C^\infty(T^*M\odot T^*M)$ and satisfies
$$\langle T(A),f\rangle_{L^2}=\langle A,T^*(f)\rangle_\color{red}{?}\tag{2}$$
for every $A\in C^\infty(T^*M\odot T^*M)$ and every $f\in C^\infty(M)$. Having learned the Lebesgue space $L^p(M)$, I don't feel pressured about the $L^2$ bracket in (2), but what should I do with the mysterious bracket in the same equation? Is that an inner product of covariant $2$-tensor fields? Much is appreciated if someone could offer an authoritative reference that clearly defines the formal adjoint of a mapping between spaces of smooth sections of vector bundles. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Fixed the tensor types of $A$ and $T$. Also, I now see that $T$ could be a differential operator.

You don't say what type of operator $T$ is, but I assume you want it to be a differential operator. My original answer assumed that $T$ was just a tensor map, which is a rather trivial case.

Let's instead assume that $T$ is a first order differential operator. In other words, given $A \in C^\infty(T^*M\otimes T^*M)$, which can be written in local coordinates as
$$
A = A_{ij}\,dx^i\otimes dx^j,
$$
the operator $T: C^\infty(T^*M\otimes T^*M) \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ is given by
$$
T(A) = \alpha^{ijk}\nabla_kA_{ij},
$$
where $\alpha = \alpha^{ijk}\,\partial_i\otimes\partial_j\otimes\partial_k \in C^\infty(T_*M\otimes T_*M\otimes T_*M)$.

There are two $L^2$ norms here, one for scalar functions,
$$
\langle f,h\rangle_{L^2} = \int_M fh\,dV
$$
and one for $2$-tensors,
\begin{align*}
\langle A,B\rangle_{L^2} &= \int_M \langle A, B\rangle\,dV\\
&= \int_M g^{ip}g^{jq}A_{ij}B_{pq}\,dV
\end{align*}

Therefore, integrating by parts, we get
\begin{align*}
\langle T(A),f\rangle_{L^2} &= \int_M T(A)f\,dV\\
&= \int \alpha^{ijk}\nabla_kA_{ij}f\,dV\\
&= \int (-\nabla_k(\alpha^{ijk}f))A_{ij}\,dV\\
&= \int \langle T^*(f),A\rangle\,dV,
\end{align*}
where $T^*: C^\infty(M) \rightarrow C^\infty(T^*M\otimes T^*M)$ is given by
$$
T^*(f) = -g_{ip}g_{jq}\nabla_k(\alpha^{pqk}f)\,dx^i\otimes dx^j.
$$

Comment: Hi Deane, I think there is a typo in your first integral: $f$ is missing

Comment: @Didier, thanks.

Comment: @Deane Why do $A$ and $T$ take on those coordinate representations? Isn't $A$ a covariant $2$-tensor field? And why is $T$ a covariant $2$-tensor field instead of a linear operator between the specified spaces? Or is it simply an instructional example out of your creation? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. I switched the tensor types. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Deane Honestly, I'm working on the linearized scalar curvature, trying to show its formal $L^2$-adjoint $DR|_g^*$ goes by $$DR|_g^*(f)=-(\Delta_g f)g+\mathrm{Hess}(f)-f\,\mathrm{Ric}_g.$$ Will it help any if I make sense of the partial integration $$\int \alpha^{ijk}\nabla_kA_{ij}f\,dV=\int (-\nabla_k(\alpha^{ijk}f))A_{ij}\,dV,$$ please? I know it might be a stupid question to you, but I'm really having a hard time justifying the asserted formula, and I really want to know what to start with. Thank you.

Comment: Linearized scalar curvature is second order, so it’s essentially the same calculation but you have to integrate by parts twice. Do as much as you can and post a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi, Professor. I didn't make out that partial integration, but I justified the formula using some partial integration formulae and Green's identities. Not sure if it is a standard practice, I also employed the assumption that $f$ and $h$ are compactly supported on $\mathrm{int}(M)$.

Comment: Yes, it is standard practice to assume compact support, because you want the boundary term to be zero. And, yes, you use Green's theorem. The key point is that $$ \partial_k(a^{ijk}A_{ij}f) = a^{ijk}\nabla_kA_{ij}f + \nabla_k(a^{ijk}f)A_{ij}. $$ and when you integrate this over $M$, the integral on the left is zero.

Comment: Yeah, I see. You are getting into the product rule. But why is $\int_M\partial_k(a^{ijk}A_{ij}f)dV_g$ vanishing? Could you possibly tell me how you came to that, please? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the adjoint operator is defined using integration by parts, and integration by parts is just the product rule.

Comment: There are two answers to this. One is that the adjoint operator is defined by simply ignoring the boundary term. The second is that the integral vanishes by Stokes's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Equation $(2)$ that you stated is exactly how the adjoint operator should be defined, in the sense that we want to have the "integration by parts" formula hold $$\langle T(A), f \rangle_{L^2} = \langle A, T^*(f) \rangle_{L^2}. $$ This is also the exact same way you define the adjoint of a bounded linear operator between two Hilbert spaces.

From the Riemannian metric on $M$, there are canonical fiber metrics on each tensor bundle over $M$, and then you can define the $L^2$ inner product of two tensors using this. For the definition of these fiber metrics, you can have a look in John Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian manifolds*, Chapter 2.

Comment: I think what confused OP about (2) is "which $L^2$ space" is involved. On the LHS, it is $L^2(M;\Bbb R)$, while on the RHS, it is $L^2(M; T^*M\odot T^*M)$.